# Is there any use for ¿ in English language?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, orthography

I know that ¿ is used in Spanish language to make questions. But I never saw that in English language. Do we use "¿" for something in English language?

I've found info about [irony ponctuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony_punctuation) but I don't know if it's applied to English currently.

Comment: No.  While it would sometimes be useful to have the convention that Spanish does of beginning questions with an upside-down question mark, such a convention has never "caught on" in any substantial population of English writers.  And the mark, while occasionally seen used for ad-hoc purposes, does not have an idiomatic use.

Comment: Can you put that as an answer so I could mark it as correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. While it would sometimes be useful to have the convention that Spanish does of beginning questions with an upside-down question mark, such a convention has never "caught on" in any substantial population of English writers. And the mark, while occasionally seen used for ad-hoc purposes, does not have some other idiomatic use.

Comment: Both this and the inverted exclamation have always seemed like useful marks to me - questions and exclamations are not always obvious from the first word.

Comment: If a question or exclamation is not 'obvious' while being read, then re-writing is to be preferred to using non-English punctuation marks.

Answer (score -1):

¿Do we use an upside down question mark at the beginning of questions in English?
Not usually, but sometimes speakers of Spanish, especially learners, find it hard not to use it when writing in English, especially informally i.e. texting etc.